# How to make a customized plot function that can plot functions with optional parameter?

Tags: plotting, functions, options, optional-arguments

Suppose I make the following function to plot contour lines for a complex function:

```
ContourRe[Func_, xrange_, yrange_, Nlines_: 30, size_: 400] := ContourPlot[Re[Func[x + I*y]],
{x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, {y, yrange[[1]], yrange[[2]]}, 
ContourShading -> False, Contours -> Nlines, ContourStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> size]
```

How can I generalize it so that the input function `Func` can have additional parameters? 
For example I have:

```
F1[z_]:=Exp[z]+3*I
F2[z_,a_:-2]:=a*Exp[z]
```

How should I modify `ContourRe` so that it can take both `F1` and `F2` as arguments and plot them?

It is like in python in which many of the built-in scipy functions have `args={}` for us to specify any parameters associated with the input function. In mathematica there are things like `OptionsPattern` and `OptionValue`, but after looking at the documentations I don't really know how to use them in this specific example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `SubValues`: define your functions with more than one `[]`. This both makes it easier to write the plotting function, and it keeps the conceptually two different things, parameters and variables, separate.

```
f2[a_:-2, b_:0][z_] := a*Exp[z] + b

contourRe[fu : (func_[args__] | func_), xrange_, yrange_, nLines_: 30, size_: 400] := ContourPlot[Re[fu[x + I*y]],
{x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, {y, yrange[[1]], yrange[[2]]}, 
ContourShading -> False, Contours -> nLines, ContourStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> size]
```

I changed the variable names to start with lower-case, both to avoid clashes with built-ins, and to make autocompletion more useful :) Now both

```
contourRe[f2[], {-2, 2}, {-3, 3}]
```

and

```
contourRe[f2[3,4], {-2, 2}, {-3, 3}]
```

work. Functions without parameters also work, e.g.

```
contourRe[Sin, {-2, 2}, {-3, 3}]
```

Comment: ,Wouldn't `a_:1` make more sense?

Comment: @Feyre, I just copied the `a` parameter from OP's `F2` :p

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am looking for. But even if the input function has no parameters, I still need to define it as func[]this method requires all the function to be defined as `func[][z_]:=Log[z]`? Are there any possible ways to handle cases like `func[z_]:=Log[z]` instead?

Comment: Sure, just copy-paste the definition I made, remove `[args___]` from both the LHS and RHS, and evaluate it. This does not overwrite the definition I made, it will just add another use-case. Since _Mathematica_ tries more specific rules first, it will work.

Comment: I've made an update to my answer that I think is even better.

Comment: Can you explain the new parts to me? '|' is 'or', right? So the argument can either be func or func[args], what about `fu:`? what does the colon mean?

Comment: `|` is `Alternatives`, the `:` is `Pattern`. You should be able to understand what they mean together by reading the respective doc pages :)

Answer (score 3):

I would refashion the plotting procedure to accept pure functions. Note that the range values (like `x1`) can be captured within parameter definition.

```
plot[f_Function, {x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}, nLines_: 30, size_: 150] :=
 ContourPlot[Re[f[x + I y]], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2},
  ContourShading -> False,
  Contours -> nLines,
  ContourStyle -> Red,
  ImageSize -> size]
```

Then:

```
(* f1 = Exp[#] + 3 I &; *)
f1 = Function[z, Exp[z] + 3 I];

f2[a_: - 2] := Function[z, a Exp[z] + Sin[a z]]

plot[f1, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
(* f2[] is the call with default a, not just f2 *)
plot[f2[.2], {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
plot[10 Log[#] &, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}]
```

[image]